# could not get the reflection type for model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

Step 1 : right click to generate

[image: this is my first step]

Step 2 : setting

[image]

Step 3 : error message

[image: My Vs2017 popup this error message, when i create the view from controller]

Step 4 : my Model

[image]

how to settle this ? i cant generate create form

Comment: Suspect it's a known issue with .Net Core scaffolding in VS 2017: https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/430

Comment: I have the same issue, however when I create a blank new project I'm able to scaffold. I have no idea what the difference is.

Comment: hi @Neo Yap, same problem here, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: see Phil.Wheeleer link. this already fix in preview 2.0

Comment: @NeoYap any luck with the solution

Comment: work good in vs2017 preview 2, but after i update preview 5. this feature is gone already.

Comment: This is an ongoing issue with every new version of c#. I'm getting it with .Net 6.0, and downgrading `LangVersion` all the way from the default `10.0` to `7.1` makes no difference. Downgrading below 7.1 is too many changes to my code to be worthwhile!

Answer (score 3):

So far even if you try to add say, another view for an existing controller and an existing action, say `ManageController.AddPhoneNumber` with the existing view model -  `AddPhoneNumberViewModel`, still the same exception is thrown despite there is already a view for the very same action and controller, using the very same view model.

No need to upload any more screenshots, or anything else, the problem seems to be in the VS 2017 code generator (a scaffolding view issue), and hopefully will be addressed in some of the following updates.

So be patient and use the copy/paste approach, you'll need to redesign your form anyway. Apparently, this is not a solution to your (my) problem, it only says - "you did nothing wrong, it's a VS bug, wait for an update".

Comment: however the error is the same for VS2019 16.3.9 so waiting or updates can take too long

Comment: @oleksa maybe you should contact the VS team @Microsoft?

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this and similar issues relating to scaffolding a number of times, and my goto solution works pretty much every time - including for this specific issue.

> 1. Right click Solution file
> 2. Select "Rebuild Solution"

...And then try your action again.

This has worked for me many times in VS2017 and VS2019 - including today with the latest VS 2019.

It seems the scaffolding is being tripped up by something that is already built, for reasons unknown.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem, make sure there are no issues in your controller, I had unfinished code that caused the error, once I commented it out it created the view without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and I solved it by downgrading the C# version from 7.2 to 7.1 from the project file

[image]

which shows an error.
[image]

I remembered that I applied some VS code hints which upgraded the C# version. the code hint was to add the paramaters name in the methods calls like

[image]

later I tried to add a view and it showed the above problem. after so many hours of searching and reaching to nothing, I started to remember the C# version change

I downgraded the C# version and removed the paramaters names then I added the view successfully.

btw the error has no relation with the model which is a great mislead.

Comment: I can't downgrade the C# language version since it is disabled in the project's properties. So I've created the emtpy view without model and added model as it is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3).

Comment: @oleksa This answer was based on early build from VS 2017. I believe this is fixed in later builds in VS 2017 and in VS 2019
Try to update your Visual Studio

Comment: well, I've tried the VS2019 16.3.9 actually but no luck

Comment: @oleksa you can downgrade, although unrelated to the main issue, in .csproj with <LangVersion> property

Comment: @Default It's very much related to the main issue. The issue is that the code generator uses an outdated version of c#. Most descriptions of this were when VS was using 7+ and the code generator 6, but it still seems to be an issue with .Net 6.0 which defaults to c# 10. So, if you have code that won't compile with the code generator's version you get this error, and downgrading `<LangVersion>` may be precisely the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, if you have created or modified the class (being used to scaffold with) and **haven't** completed a build yet, build the project first and then try again.

.NET is unable to scaffold any classes that haven't been built yet.

Comment: yep. I had to do the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I sincerely don't know what happened, reverting to an old version of code fixes it.

Things I tried that didn't work

- Rebuild
- Clean / delete bin obj folders
- use a different model
- use a different template
- upgrade visual studio
- make sure there are no compile errors.

Things I know isn't the problem

- Model classes that inherit other classes

Things I suspect is a problem but haven't tested.

- generic methods with same parameters only differing by generics constraint

I can provide the code and details if interested.

Comment: The clean and then rebuild worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error, but none of the above solutions worked for me.
Turned out there was one deprecated NuGet Package installed which somehow messed up the scaffolding.

So for those who are having the same issue but nothing works - Check your project for unnescessary and outdated packages.
In my case this was Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity in Version 2.2.0.  Removing it fixed the error for me and the project still runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with you, but I manage to solved the problem with following method:

1. build project (will see build failed).
2. Solve the project until successfully build the project.
3. then, add/generate View again. (should be able to auto-generate the View)

Answer (score 0):

Probably is a long time since this issue was posted here, but I got the same problem using the VS2019 (16.9.2) and/or dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator from command line.

After hours and days searching, no of the solutions mentioned above worked for me, and I ended up by find the reason.

The reason behind this was that I was starting first by implementing my Controller which is calling a Web API to get or post data asynchronously. So almost methods were made async.

To solve the problem, I had to scaffold first the controller and **keep the default implementation**. Then the scaffolding of the views completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turned out my `Program` class wasn't called `Program` in ASP.NET Core Web API. Naming it back to `Program` solved it.