# Could not get the reflection type for DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

When scaffolding a controller in ASP Core 2.0 VS 2017 I get the following:

> Could not get the reflection type for DbContext :
>
> BE.Data.ApplicationDbContext    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.b__6_0()
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[]
> args)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[]
> args)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[]
> args)

This all of a sudden has occurred, and a colleague running the same code does not get this problem, I had tried clean builds, deleting the bin and obj folders in each project, deleting the db and still I cannot seem to work it out, would appreciate any help.

Model:

```
public class SettingType : BaseModel
{
    public int SettingTypeId { get; set; }
    public string SettingTypeDescription { get; set; }
    public string SystemCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any C#7 new features in your project?

Comment: @S.Akbari: Why? We haven't started using them quite yet. Does that create problems with EF scaffolding?

Comment: @EricJ. I had a similar problem with one of my projects and the problem solved by replacing one of the C#7 new features!

Comment: Did you upgrade the VS to v15.3 or later?

Comment: @S.Akbari Yes. 7.1, I am using the
public static async Task Main(string[] args) feature.

Comment: @IvanStoev V15.4.3 (Latest - Upgraded)

Comment: @DavidBeaumont Test if it works without this new feature.

Comment: @S.Akbari It worked by changing my Project Language Version to C#6.0 and refactoring some of the 7/7.1 features. Strange! Thanks, might be a bug? I can mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: This worked for me follow this [link ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47071988/7683231)

Comment: I have answered a similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68787700/945317 if it helps somebody :-)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I had this issue too, when I was using the new C#7 feature ([expression bodied members and Throw expressions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/)) but by replacing my code with it's equivalent in C#6 it didn't give me that error anymore. Try to test your project without any C#7 new feature and probably it should works fine. I'm not sure what is the reason but I think The Roslyn packages that scaffolding depends on does not support C#7 new features yet.

As a workaround to let scaffolding works with C#7 I think you can by doing the following:

1. Install (or update) NuGet package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces` version 2.0.0 or higher
2. And then retry to scaffolding again

Comment: Same issue on VS2019. Worked for me.

Comment: Same issue VS2019 16.6.0 Preview 2.1.  Worked for me.

Comment: Same thing happened to me in a .Net 5.0 project under VS 16.8.2 and this fixed it. Removing the expression bodied members didn't work, I had to install the CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces (version 3.8). I should try going back to expression bodied members to see if it will still work.

Comment: I added back the expression bodied members and scaffolding still works.

Comment: Worked for me, installed the latest Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces nuget

Comment: Got this issue in VS 2022. This solved it for me!

Comment: Not working in VS2022 .Net 6.0 - When trying to install this package I get a version conflict with Microsoft.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package. When I install an older version of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces it doesn't have a conflict. However, when running the scaffolder then it DELETES the Microsoft.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package and gives error: Add Microsoft.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package to the project. Thank you Microsoft, you're so great with your versions

Answer (score 2):

I'm using visual studio 2019 and .Net Core 3.1

I just realized that somewhere in my code I had used `unsafe { }` block. I commented unsafe code for temporary and I can scaffold again.

Answer (score 1):

I get this error when I generate the EF model by Scaffold-DbContext command and this finished with warnings. Then firstable I correct the warnings of Scaffold-DbContext and then scaffold razor items works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There were an ambiguity when trying to scaffold-dbContext. 
i try to scaffold again and errors appeared on the dbcontext. it was an ambiguous use of a term. 
resolving this ambiguity fond on the list of errors. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, just needed to build the project after the scaffolding. (Yes, its a basic thing to do, but I forgot about it haha)

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me (core .net6). I even closed the Solution -> Clean it --> rebuilt it and voila it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with this. My connection string to the database contained language specific symbols (latvian) and i just could not figure that out for 2 hours. I fixed it by placing my project folder and database in a directory that contained only ASCII symbols.

Maybe comes useful for someone.

Comment: Had the same problem. renamed the project name to not include "ä" in it. Followed this guide for renaming: [How to Rename an ASP.NET Core Project](https://blog.pragtechnologies.com/how-to-rename-an-asp-net-core-project/)

Answer (score 1):

A different cause for the error... an unusual and invisible character in the code file. One of the errors from the scaffolding of a controller reported a line number with no obvious error, but did report CS1056 Unexpected character.

I found the character using a regular expression search found [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/kon/finding-those-pesky-unicode-characters-in-visual-studio). It's the yellow square in the screen capture below. After deleting it, the scaffolding of a controller completed without errors.

Visual Studio 2022 Community, Version 17.4.4

[image]

Comment: Holy cow! Same thing here, copy-pasting from a simple example in the official microsoft learn page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you don't have any deprecated packages installed, as this is what caused this problem for me. I had Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity installed and uninstalling allowed me to scaffold again.