# Scaffolding in Asp.net Core and EntityFramework Core is giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have a project that I have been working on for quite a while.  It is an Asp.net Core project currently using SDK 2.1.403.  I am using VS 2017 15.9.0 preview 3 as by IDE.  The project utilizes Entity Framework Core, and I have been scaffolding my models successfully up until today.

I did some refactoring of the database entity names and relationships this morning, and since then I am getting the following error when trying to scaffold a new controller.  It also breaks trying to scaffold an individual View.

> Could not get the reflection type for DbContext :   AurigoPriceCalculator.Models.AurigoPricingCalculatorContext

I have tried creating a new test project with the same version of Visual Studio and it is able to scaffold new controllers, so there obviously is something wrong with my current project.

I have read through similar problems identified on stackoverflow, however, none of the solutions provided address my issue.  The previously reported problems are all related to pre release SDKs and c# 7.0 features.  These issues and solutions identified are supposedly addressed prior to 2.1.403

I am at a standstill and I am not even sure how to begin to debug the issue.  Can someone help me understand how to debug this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not get the reflection type for DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060751/could-not-get-the-reflection-type-for-dbcontext)

Comment: I saw this answer but I dont have any c# 7 code and the issue that is referred to is resolved in 3.1

Comment: Honestly, I would just switch to the new project that works and move on with your life lol.  If you really want to dig, you could get the projects as close together as you can, then diff them. Or you can at least share your `DbContext` class code here as the starting point.