# Having trouble adding a scaffolded item to asp.net Core App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am learning Asp.net core from .net's Official site. I am facing the following error While scaffolding a controller in Asp.net Core 3.1.
I have already seen that someone posted the same problem before but I don't understand the solution given by other developers. Can anyone please tell me what to do explicitly? I am new to .NET, thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot of the Error]

Comment: Could you reopen your vs and rebuild your project?Also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060751/could-not-get-the-reflection-type-for-dbcontext/47071988

Comment: @XingZou thanks It worked after rebuilding the project .There was a simple syntax mistake . Its working after fixing the mistake .