# Issue, VS 19 ASP.NET Core 3.1 when I start to create "MVC Controller with view, using Entity Framework"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2019, dbcontext, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1, I already created the controller, it worked for me, after a few days I need to create a controller for `ShoppingCartItem`, hereafter I face some issues.

My model

```
namespace NCCMobileTest.Data.Model
{
    public class ShoppingCartItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }


        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }

        // from Item table
        public int Item_Id { get; set; }
        public Customer customer { get; set; }

        // from generat bill no
        public int Bill_No { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My `DbContext`

```
namespace NCCMobileTest.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Some screenshots of my steps

- how I create my controller: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSq4W.png)
- error message: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBuGm.png)

Output

```
Finding the generator 'controller'...
Running the generator 'controller'...
Attempting to compile the application in memory.
Could not get the reflection type for DbContext : NCCMobileTest.Data.ApplicationDbContext
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
```

Comment: check here it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/47071988/2419696

Comment: @PrasadPhule I already tried. same error occurs

Answer (score 0):

`IdentityDbContext` inherits from `DbContext`?

If not, have you tried changing to

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
```

Comment: If your DbContext in a separate project, class library project. Please check also idesigntimedbcontextfactory. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.idesigntimedbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

Recently I experienced a similar problem. After a lot of hours of skepticism and debugging, I understood the problem was that I have renamed my `Startup` class to `StartUp` and that caused the whole error.

I cannot be sure if that certainly is your problem, but it is worth checking it.