# Could not get the Reflection type for DBContext in ASP.NET Core 5.0 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am using ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC with the latest version of c# and VS2019 community, and I keep getting an error.

I tried to:

- Rebuild the project
- Change the c# version to 6/7/7.1
- Re-install VS2019
- and some other solutions that you provided in previous posts that were for VS 2019 and ASP.NET Core 2.0 but the error remains.

The problem is still there

Here is some of my code

MyDb context

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{

    
   public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TestTabel> testTabels { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Admin> Admins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Hotel> Hotels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Chambre> Chambres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BonReservation> BonsReservations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ListHotelOwners> ListHotelOwners { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> address { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Roles> Role { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add indexs and unique keys to all tables 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelBuilder"></param>
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //User Table
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasIndex(u => u.NomUtilisateur)
            .IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasIndex(u => u.NomPrenom)
            .IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasIndex(u => u.NumTelephone)
            .IsUnique();

        // Role Table
        modelBuilder.Entity<Roles>()
            .HasIndex(r => r.Nom).IsUnique();

        //Address Table

        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasIndex(a => a.Maison).IsUnique();



    }
}
```

my test Class

```
public class TestTabel
{
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(30)")]
    public string username { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(30)")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Project Structure
'[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg00b.jpg)'

error
'[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcPoH.jpg)'

Comment: What error are you talking about? Also,this community asks that code is put in the question as text, not as screenshots, and definitely not as links to screenshots.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not get the reflection type for DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060751/could-not-get-the-reflection-type-for-dbcontext)

Comment: @BryanDellinger i tried that and the problem still remains the same, i added a screnshot to the  error

Comment: @Crowcoder i added the code in the question and a screenshot of the error