# Scaffold View with ViewModel in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-5.0, ef-core-5.0, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I am trying to scaffold views based on a ViewModel in ASP.NET Core 5 project and have been finding it difficult passing through the following stage

[image]

I used to be able to pass this stage by deleting the Data Context field but that seems to have become impossible recently. Any ideas on how to scaffold a razor view with a ViewModel on ASP.Net Core 5?

With the DataContext field, it generates an error as shown

[image]

The model doesnt need a key. It is a ViewModel. It does not even need to be in the AppDbContext file and it does not need to be be in the database for any reason

Comment: @mason The model doesnt need a key. It is a viewmodel

Comment: For me,It is still possible to generate scaffolding for `Viewmodel` by not specifying `DbContext`.

Comment: @Yinqiu In my case, I used to be able to leave that field blank but not anymore. Could it be the version of Visual Studio that I am using? I always update to the latest version

Comment: I have the same issue any update?  NetCore 3

Comment: @SteveNewton No update yet. I have two laptops. It works as expected on one of the laptops and this issue persists on the other. Both are running Visual Studio 2019 updated to the latest updates

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm having the same issue here with the latest version of VS 2019 and VS Code, I tried all recommendations without success

Comment: @SomeCode.Net No solution yet.

Comment: @Josh I have answered a similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68787700/945317

Comment: As @Yinqiu stated, you can generate scaffolding for a `ViewModel` **without** specifying a "Data context class" even if it is written as "Required" in Visual Studio. It worked for me for a project in .Net 5 with Visual Studio 16.11.9. Keep in mind that there is no `Controller` generated, only a View (as requested). Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

The datacontext class says it's required but it's actually not.
I had the same problem and you can just leave it like it is

[image]

empty and Click Add.

ASP.NET CORE 7